# Set Registry Value to a Wide Character String (WCHAR) in C++

Tags: c++, registry

I'm trying to add a wide character string to registry in C++. The problem is that the `RegSetValueEx()` function does not support wide chars, it only supports `BYTE` type (`BYTE` = `unsigned char`).

```
WCHAR myPath[] = "C:\\éâäà\\éâäà.exe"
RegSetValueExA(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "MyProgram", 0, REG_SZ, myPath, sizeof(myPath)); // error: cannot convert argument 5 from WCHAR* to BYTE*
```

And please don't tell me I should convert `WCHAR` to `BYTE` because characters such as `é` and `â` can't be stored as 8 bit characters.

I'm sure this is possible because I tried opening `regedit` and adding a new key with value `C:\\éâäà\\éâäà.exe` and it worked. I wonder how other programs can add themselves to startup on a Russian or Chinese computer.

Is there another way to do so? Or is there a way to format wide character path using wildcards?

**Edit:** The Unicode version of the function `RegSetValueExW()` only changes the type of the second argument.

Comment: Use `RegSetValueExW`. The A suffix means the narrow char version; W means wide char.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `RegSetValueExA()` when you should be calling `RegSetValueExW()` instead.  But in either case, `RegSetValueEx()` writes *bytes*, not *characters*, that is why the `lpData` parameter is declared as `BYTE*`.  Simply type-cast your character array.  The `REG_SZ` value in the `dwType` parameter will let `RegSetValueEx()` know that the bytes represent a Unicode string. And make sure to include the null terminator in the value that you pass to the `cbData` parameter, per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923.aspx):

> cbSize [in]
>   The size of the information pointed to by the lpData parameter, **in bytes**. If the data is of type REG_SZ, REG_EXPAND_SZ, or REG_MULTI_SZ, **cbData must include the size of the terminating null character or characters**.

For example:

```
WCHAR myPath[] = L"C:\\éâäà\\éâäà.exe";
RegSetValueExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"MyProgram", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)myPath, sizeof(myPath));
```

Or:

```
LPCWSTR myPath = L"C:\\éâäà\\éâäà.exe";
RegSetValueExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"MyProgram", 0, REG_SZ, (LPCBYTE)myPath, (lstrlenW(myPath) + 1) * sizeof(WCHAR));
```

That being said, you should not be writing values to the root of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` itself.  You should be writing to a subkey instead, eg:

```
WCHAR myPath[] = L"C:\\éâäà\\éâäà.exe";

if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\MyProgram", 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_SET_VALUE, NULL, &hKey, NULL) == 0)
{
    RegSetValueExW(hKey, L"MyValue", 0, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)myPath, sizeof(myPath));
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're trying to use the narrow/non-wide-char version of that function, which will only support ASCII.  How about trying `RegSetValueExW`?  Maybe you should also look up how the Windows API tries to supports ASCII and UNICODE as transparently as possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: The Unicode version of the function RegSetValueExW() only changes the type of the second argument.

No it does not.

> REG_SZ: A null-terminated string. This will be either a Unicode or an ANSI string, **depending on whether you use the Unicode or ANSI functions.**

From here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types