# Adding a file path into the registry using RegSetValueEx

Tags: c++, registry

I am trying to add a program in the registry to start when the computer boots. However when it does add itself, under "Data" it has some Chinese words, where I would like to add the file path instead. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    HKEY hkey;
    LONG regoOpenResult;
    const char PATH[] = "C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop\\FILENAME.bat";

    regoOpenResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);

    RegSetValueEx(hkey, L"StartUpProgram", 0, REG_SZ,(BYTE*)PATH, strlen(PATH));

    RegCloseKey(hkey);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32408791/1625187).

Comment: Thank you so so much You have literally saved my life and my A in my senior design project